# How much overhead does a msg_send call incur?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I'm attempting to piece together and run a list of tasks put together by a user.  These task lists can be hundreds or thousand of items long.

From what I know, the easiest and most obvious way would be to build an array and then iterate through them:

```
NSArray *arrayOfTasks = .... init and fill with thousands of tasks

for (id *eachTask in arrayOfTasks)
{
  if ( eachTask && [eachTask respondsToSelector:@selector(execute)] ) [eachTask execute];
}
```

For a desktop, this may be no problem, but for an iphone or ipad, this may be a problem.  Is this a good way to go about it, or is there a faster way to accomplish the same thing?

The reason why I'm asking about how much overhead a msg_send occurs is that I could also do a straight C implementation as well.  For example, I could put together a linked list and use a block to handle the next task.  Will I gain anything from that or is it really more trouble than its worth?

Comment: You don't need to check whether `eachTask` is non-nil. `respondsToSelector:` will result in NO if `eachTask` is nil, or it doesn't respond to `execute`.

Comment: You're not going to get a `nil` value out of an NSArray anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're talking about `objc_msgSend`, in which case, Bill Bumgarner has an excellent
[4 Part Series](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/) that is worth a read.

In general though, I would recommend simply using Obj-C. This is what all apps for the iDevices use, including Apple, and hundreds of items is not going to kill the device.

Comment: just an addendum to my comment... i like getting into the guts of things, and apple's documentation does only go so far... so this really is a great article!

Answer (score 1):

What rynmrtn said...

Unless your `-execute` methods were exceedingly simplistic -- incrementing / testing a small handful of scalar values -- then it is unlikely that `objc_msgSend()` will even show up as a % of your program's CPU time.

Measure first, optimize after.

Your code does raise a question;  why are you putting things into the `arrayOfTasks` that might not be able to `execute`.   Assuming everything in your `arrayOfTasks` is a subclass of your making, you could add an `execute` method and not do the *responds* test.   If you have a hierarchy of collection classes, you could use categories to add the methods -- just put a prefix on 'em to be safe (i.e. `pxl_execute` or something).

Comment: i probably should've used pseudo code, but the idea is going through a list of thousands of objects and calling a method for each of them

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html) is a nice benchmark comparison of common operations, including `objc_msgSend`.  In general, you shouldn't worry about `objc_msgSend` performance, even on the iPhone.  Message sending will always be slower than a straight C function call, but on a modern processor (remember, the iPhone processor is still about 500 mhz), the difference is trivial most of the time.  If profiling shows that a lot of time is being used in `objc_msgSend`, then it might be worth using straight C functions instead of Objective-C methods.

For clarity, you can use `-[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]` or (on Mac) `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` instead of iterating through the objects, but I don't think it should make much performance difference.

Comment: thanks!  from the comments and what i'm reading on my own, I really shouldn't worry much at all about objc_msgSend, and to just get out something that works.  Then, like you suggest, run performance benchmarks and start finding where all the bottlenecks and slow points are.